# why is Producer printing 3 times? Producer and Consumer problem

Tags: c++, linux

This is the task:

> Achieve communication between processes running in parallel using a limited length buffer. The program receives two input parameters via the command line. The first parameter indicates the number of the manufacturer's processes, and the second parameter indicates the number of random numbers that each manufacturer must generate and put in the clipboard. The consumer receives number by number from the manufacturer via the clipboard and calculates their sum. After receiving all the numbers from all the manufacturers and calculating their sum, the sum should be printed on the screen.

*It is supposed to look like this:*

```
Producer 3 sending "516"
Consumer receives 516 
Producer 2 sending "348"
Consumer receives 348
Producer 3 sending "978"
Consumer receives 978
Producer 2 sending "347"
Consumer receives 347
Producer 3 finished with sending
Producer 2 finished with sending
Producer 1 sending "519"
Producer 1 sending "220"
Consumer receives 519
Consumer receives 220
Consumer - sum of taken numbers=7575
Producer 1 finished with sending
```

But it keeps printing Producer 3 times at once for example:

```
Producer 3 sending "222"
Producer 3 sending "516"
Producer 3 sending "125"
```

and then the Consumer doesn't get to receive in time.

*And this is my code:*

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <csignal>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

using namespace std;

int i;
int sem_id;
int mem_id;
int zbroj;
int m, n;

struct med
{
    int meduspremnik[5];
    int ULAZ, IZLAZ, UKUPNO;
}*medo;


int PISI = 0;
int PUN = 1;
int PRAZAN = 2;


sembuf semafori;


void postavi(int sem_id)
{
     semafori.sem_num = sem_id;
     semafori.sem_op = 1;
     semop(sem_id, &semafori, 1);
}

void ispitaj(int sem_id)
{
    semafori.sem_num = sem_id;
    semafori.sem_op = -1;
    semop(sem_id, &semafori, 1);
}


void kraj(int sig)
{
    shmdt(medo);
    shmctl(mem_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    shmctl(sem_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    exit(sig);
}

void proizvodac(int proizv)
{
    int neka = proizv + 1;
    i = 0;
    do
    {
        ispitaj(PUN);
        ispitaj(PISI);
        medo->meduspremnik[medo->ULAZ] = rand() % 1000;
        cout << "Proizvodac " << neka << " salje: " << "''" << medo->meduspremnik[medo->ULAZ] << "''" << endl;
        medo->ULAZ = (medo->ULAZ + 1) % 5;
        sleep(1);
        postavi(PISI);
        postavi(PRAZAN);
        i = i + 1;
    }while(i < n);
    cout << "Proizvodac " << neka << " zavrsio sa slanjem." << endl;
}

void potrosac()
{
    i = 0;
    zbroj = 0;
    do
    {
        sleep(1);
        ispitaj(PRAZAN);
        cout << "Potrosac prima " << medo->meduspremnik[medo->IZLAZ] << "." << endl;
        zbroj += medo->meduspremnik[medo->IZLAZ];
        medo->IZLAZ = (medo->IZLAZ+1) % 5;
        postavi(PUN);
        i = i+1;
    }while (i < n*m);
    cout << "Potrosac - zbroj primljenih brojeva= " << zbroj << endl;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    m = atoi(argv[1]);
    n = atoi(argv[2]);

    semafori.sem_flg = 0;

    sem_id = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, m, 0600);
    semctl(sem_id, 0, SETVAL, 1);
    semctl(sem_id, 1, SETVAL, 5);
    semctl(sem_id, 2, SETVAL, 0);

    mem_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(med), 0600);


    medo = (med*) shmat(mem_id, NULL, 0);
    medo->ULAZ = 0;
    medo->IZLAZ = 0;
    medo->UKUPNO = m*n;
    m++;

    sigset(SIGINT, kraj);

    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        switch(fork())
        {
            case 0:
                if(i == 0)
                {
                    potrosac();
                }
                else
                {
                    proizvodac(i);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        wait(NULL);
    }

    kraj(0);

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: When the child-processes finish, what will they do? Hint: They won't exit the process or the loop.

Comment: But I have break; in the switch(fork()), doesn't that make them exit the process?

Comment: `break` breaks the `case` in the `switch`. Then the loop continues. To exit a process you must either return from `main` or call `exit`.

Comment: I put exit instead of break but the problem stays the same.

Comment: Then you need to *debug* your program. Debugging multi-process programs in a debugger is rather hard, so begin by adding a lot of extra output in your code. For example print when a function is called, or when you return from a function. Print all values in all calculations. And for ***all*** output, also print the pid and parent-pid to know exactly which process the output came fromn.

Comment: IPC via the clipboard? What a bizarre assignment. Your code would be easier for us to debug if it was written in english

Comment: You did make your output easier to follow by translating it into the language of your post (English); this much is good. However, you should translate the output statements in your code as well. Here's my approach to seeing if I might be able to help: I double-clicked one of the words in the actual output (e.g. `sending`), the hit `ctrl-f` to find where that appears in this web page. Guess what? That text appears *nowhere* in your code, so this approach failed. Your code and your output should be consistent with each other.

Comment: You described your symptom as *"keeps printing Producer 3 times at once"*, but I see *three* symptoms in that one description. **1)** There is no output from consumers. **2)** The only producer that has output is number 3. **3)** Producer 3 never reports that it is finished sending. Is that accurate? (If not, please provide complete output.) If it is, you should trim your code to a [mre] that focuses on *one* symptom. I'd start with getting output from all three producers; instead of your assignment's task, try to get the output `Producer 1` `Producer 2` `Producer 3` (in any order).